# How can I type this type of "A" in latex?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I need this "A" in a formula, but I don't know how to type it in latex or this font's name. I've tried `\mathcal{},\mathscr` but they didn't match. So, how can I type this "A" in latex?

[image: A]

Comment: That’s `\mathcal{A}`, with a math package loaded that changes the font. Possibly `newtxmath` or `newpxmath`. Checking the fonts of the PDF with `pdffonts` might confirm it.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a calligraphic *A* in the font usually used with Times- and Palatino-like fonts. For example it is the calligraphic font automatically loaded by `newtxmath` and `newpxmath`.

If you want to load only the calligraphic font to associate with `\mathcal`, the easiest way is probably to use the `mathalpha` package with option `cal=pxtx`, as in the following example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[cal=pxtx]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\( \mathcal{A} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]